# Sql Query to find out the parent task and child task

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that content this type of info.
In this entry id is used as a unique id and ind_id is '0' if if doesn't have a parent task and if ind_id content a value it mentioned a entry_id of the parent task.

workflow

```
a-- no child
b-- child is c
  c-- parent is b
d-- child f
  f-- parent d, child e
    e-- parent f child g 
    o-- parent f child g
      g-- parent e no child
  .....more sub task may come ......
h-- no child
  i-- parent h 
j-- no child
k-- no child
```

Example table below.

```
entry_id | task            | ind_id | date
------------------------------------------------
1001     | example_1       | 0      | 22-08-2020
1000     | example_1       | 0      | 22-08-2020
1012     | example_3       | 1000   | 22-08-2020
1013     | example_4       | 1000   | 22-08-2020
1004     | example_1_14    | 0      | 22-08-2020
1006     | example_2_4     | 1004   | 22-08-2020
1007     | example_8_4     | 1006   | 22-08-2020
1010     | example_4_1     | 0      | 22-08-2020
```

I would like to get the data like this.

```
entry_id | task            | ind_id |parent_task_name | child_task_name      | date
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1001     | example_1       | 0      |null             |null                  | 22-08-2020
1000     | example_1       | 0      |null             |example_3, example_4  | 22-08-2020
1012     | example_3       | 1000   |example_1        |null                  | 22-08-2020
1013     | example_4       | 1000   |example_1        |null                  | 22-08-2020
1004     | example_1_14    | 0      |null             |example_2_4           | 22-08-2020
1006     | example_2_4     | 1004   |example_1_14     |example_8_4           | 22-08-2020
1007     | example_8_4     | 1006   |example_2_4      |null                  | 22-08-2020
1010     | example_4_1     | 0      |null             |null                  | 22-08-2020
```

Would anyone help me to find a solving for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE to define the path for each entry and then sort by that:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select entry_id, concat(entry_id) as path
      from t
      where ind_id = 0
      union all
      select t.entry_id, concat_ws('>', path, t.entry_id)
      from cte join
           t
           on t.ind_id = cte.entry_id
     )
select t.*
from t join
     cte
     on t.entry_id = cte.entry_id
order by cte.path;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d7b86a55eabf98a20a3b4d7efd263769) is a db<>fiddle.

Important note:  This works for your sample data because all the entry ids are the same length.  If they are not, then format or pad them to be a constant length.  That way, sorting the string produces the results you expect.

Comment: @ArunSolomon . . . I included a db<>fiddle showing that it works.  The results are in `entry_id` order, so 1000 is before 1001, but that just makes sense.

Comment: This is not fetch the result like what i want.